# C# Local Printer Managemt Application

Tags: c#, database, printing, wmi

The summer holidays are here and I want to try something with C#

I would like to export a local installed printer(With IP-Based communication) with all settings and upload the exported settings to a database.
A second C# application should be able to create a new local printer with the settings which are stored in the database.

So my Main question is, is something like that possible? (I'm completely new in Printermanagement with WMI)

My second question, does someone have any good links?